# Axiom of Regularity and infinite sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm wrestling with the elementary implications of the Axiom of Regularity.

The axiom:

$∀A(A≠∅→(∃x∈A)(A∩x=∅))$

implies that every set A either has $∅∈A$, or it has some element $x$ such that $x∩A=∅$.

My questions:
(1) If $x∈A$, and $x$ is not a subset (or, x is a subset that consists of only one element, i.e. {1}), then does $x∩A=∅$? I'm trying to understand how $x∩\{1,2,3\}=∅$

(2)How does this guarantee no infinitely descending sequences?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

You’ve stated the axiom of regularity correctly,

$$\forall A\Big(A\ne\varnothing\to\exists x\in A(A\cap x=\varnothing)\Big)\;,\tag{1}$$

but your verbal paraphrase isn’t quite right: $(1)$ says that either $A=\varnothing$, or some element $x$ of $A$ is disjoint from $A$. That is, your first alternative should be $A=\varnothing$, not $\varnothing\in A$.

Your first question isn’t entirely clear. In the specific example, are you asking what element of $A=\{1,2,3\}$ is disjoint from $A$? In order to answer that, you have to have some definition of $1,2$, and $3$ as sets. The usual one is that $1=\{0\},2=\{0,1\}$, and $3=\{0,1,2\}$. If you’re using that definition, then $x=1$ works:

$$x\cap A=1\cap\{1,2,3\}=\{0\}\cap\{1,2,3\}=\varnothing\;,$$

because the only element of $1$ is $0$, and $0\notin\{1,2,3\}$.

For your second question, suppose that $A=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a family of sets with the property that $a_{n+1}\in a_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$:

$$\ldots\in a_4\in a_3\in a_2\in a_1\in a_0\;.$$

Let $x\in A$. Then $x=a_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and $a_{n+1}\in x\cap A$, so $a_{n+1}\ne\varnothing$. Since $A$ is clearly non-empty, this contradicts $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for another helpful explanation! I was assuming that 1,2,3 were defined by the standard construction of natural numbers and I apologize for mistakenly omitting that assumption.

Comment: @user84815: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

First, the alternative isn't $\emptyset \in A$, as you have it, but $\emptyset=A$.  Hence every nonempty $A$ has an element that isn't a subset.

Suppose now that $$A=\{1,2,\{1\}, \{\{1\}\},\{1,2,4\},3\}$$

If we take $x=\{1\}$, then $x\cap A=\{1\}\neq \emptyset$.  If we take $x=\{1,2,4\}$, then $x\cap A=\{1,2\}\neq\emptyset$.  However if we take $x=1$, then $x\cap A=\emptyset$.

Suppose now that there were an infinitely descending subsequence $$x_1\ni x_2 \ni x_3 \ni \cdots$$

We could then take $$A=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$$ which would voilate the axiom, because for each $i$, $A\cap x_i$ is a set which contains $x_{i+1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This definitely clears things up.